# How and when are conference best paper awards sent?

Tags: conference, awards

If someone wins a best paper award at a conference, how are such awards sent to the awardees?

Also, **how long** does it take for this process to occur after the presentation is done at the conference?

Comment: Depends how customized the awards are. I've seen generic ones handed out at the conference, if they are going to put your name on it it may take longer.

Comment: The award itself is not something that is "sent", it's immaterial. You will normally receive a certificate, which used to be awarded during the conference, and in these times might in many cases arrive via email. They could also send a physical copy. I's impossible to say how long this takes, mostly depends on how high it is in the responsible persons' priority list.